# Is it better to store objects containing information in a separate .js file or in my database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating an RPG game web app and would like to store predetermined information about skills and traits.  I.e. an array of objects defining things like "Battle-hardened gives +2 strength" and "Ruthless past gives -1 social".

I'm creating this using Express and NodeJS for my application, Mongoose & MongoDB for my database, and HTML as the front end.  I am relatively new to this, so apologies if this is a simple question!

My initial thought was to create a Mongoose Schema for relevant attributes, i.e.:

```js
const attributeSchema = new Schema({
    type: String, //i.e. trait, skill, background
    description: String, //flavortext
    modifiers: {
        stats: {
            strength: Number,
            social: Number,
            //etc...
        },
        skills: {
            melee: Number,
            ballistics: Number,
            //etc...
        }
    }
});
```

Then, I would create a .js file to run which creates and saves all of the information to MongoDB via the above schema, thereby "seeding" the database.  If I ever need to add new traits/skills (e.g. in the future I introduce a new trait "Smelly Armpits" or something that causes -3 social), I would have to create new scripts to add those.  ...unless there's a better way of doing this that I haven't learned!

My other idea was to just put this all in a static .js file as one object that I could `require` when necessary or as an `app.locals` variable.  E.g.

```js
const attributes = {
  traits: [
    {
      name: 'Coffee Breath',
      description: 'Try brushing your teeth sometime!',
      modifiers: [{social: -1}]
    },
    {
      name: 'Echoes of the Void',
      description: 'The voices, they whisper to you...',
      modifiers: [{sanity: -999}, {intelligence: +2}]
    }
  ],
  //etc...
}
```

Please let me know if there is a recommended way to do this, or if there is something I am missing/could be doing better!

Comment: "Better" is subjective, what may be better to one person or even one project may not be better for another person/project even if the circumstances are the same for both. Go with whatever works for you and your project. Change it if it ends being problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple project, storing such things in a json file is probably a better idea.

Given your characters don't inherit properties from each other, setting up MongoDB is not the wisest choice in my opinion.

Additionally, often times setting up Mongoose and a database takes effort and is overly complicated for a given use case.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked with a couple friends as well, and, while I got differing answers, the majority consensus seems to be that putting this sort of simple information in a static .js/.json file is adequate.